# Ansible fact sort data (Cisco ACI)

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to get a routing table from a Cisco ACI. I'm getting duplicate routes. Is there a way to sort them out?

example:

```
        "10.127.32.70/32",
        "10.127.32.70/32",
        "10.127.32.70/32",
        "10.127.32.70/32",
        "10.127.32.70/32",
        "10.127.32.70/32"
```

after duplicate filter:

```
        "10.127.32.70/32"
```

```yaml
  - name: Get Route table (vars tenant and VRF)
    aci_rest:
      <<: *aci_login
      path: api/node/class/uribv4Nexthop.json?query-target-filter=wcard(uribv4Nexthop.dn,"sys/uribv4/dom\-C_Lab:LAB_VRF/db\-rt")
      method: "get"
    register: response 

#  - debug:
#      var: response

  - name: Create a subnet list item
    set_fact:
      array_content: "{{ item['uribv4Nexthop']['attributes']['addr'] }}" 
    with_items: 
      - "{{ response['imdata'] }}"
    register: array_of_contents  
  
  - name: Make a list with all the subnet items
    set_fact: 
         data_struc: "{{ array_of_contents.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.array_content') | list }}"

  - debug:
      var: data_struc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter [unique](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.unique), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ data_struc|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - 10.127.32.70/32
```

---

Q: *"**Get addresses with /24 only**"*

A: Use filter [ipaddr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#ipaddr-filter), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        prefix_24: "{{ prefix_24|d([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ data_struc|unique }}"
      when: item|ipaddr('prefix') == 24
      vars:
        data_struc:
          - 10.127.32.70/32
          - 10.127.32.71/24
          - 10.127.32.71/24
          - 10.127.32.72/32
```

gives

```yaml
  prefix_24:
  - 10.127.32.71/24
```

Comment: Great, it is working now.

is there a way to sort /32 so i only get addresses with /24 in the result ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Open a new question if you have more issues.